# Office is not genuine, application will be marked as non genuine meaning?

Tags: microsoft-office

I have registered my ms office pro when it was installed on my laptop in 2005.  Now i am being told MS office is not genuine.  In 3 days Office applications will be marked as not genuine.  What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

When loading updates for Office the current license key is sent back to Microsoft to verify authenticity. During this the key is matched against a list of valid keys, and the reason the key no longer work could be:

- The MSDN/Action Pack/Volume License agreement for non-retail key expired
- The key was used by more then x amount of users and is considered a pirated key.

Effectively by making the software non genuine service packs and updates cannot be applied, and in some cases functionality is also disabled until a valid key is supplied. If you do have a legit license give the Microsoft License Centre a call and they will be able to assist you with getting your copy registered again.

Answer (score 0):

The following Knowledge Base Articles can provide more information for Office Activation issues:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/903275/en-us

It's possible that you don't have an authentic copy of the Office software.  You may have a pirated version.  If you find that to be the case, I would go back to who you purchased the computer from and get them to give you a genuine copy of the software.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like MS has decided that your Office key has been compromised in some way. I don't know the details, but it could be something like it's being used on more than 2 computers concurrently (but probably isn't exactly that).

While you could have a pirated version of Office, the fact that it's been working for a while (assuming you installed Windows (Office?) Genuine Advantage some time ago) contradicts that.

If you have the original genuine media/license key you should be able to contact Microsoft and explain the situation. If you haven't installed Office elsewhere then they might give you a new key.